# Which view controller should I pass in my Swift native code for a Flutter plugin?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, plugins

I am trying to show an Adcolony ad from Swift native code in my Flutter plugin, this is how my swift code looks like -

```
 if let interstitial = self.interstitial, !interstitial.expired, let 
  rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
  {
   interstitial.show(withPresenting: rootViewController)
   }
```

My code works perfectly, but my view controller never displays an interstitial ad. Can anyone help me as I don't know which view controller should I pass to show my ad. The documentation says to use `self` but my plugin is not a view controller so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let vc = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController  as? FlutterViewController {
  interstitial.show(withPresenting: vc)
}
```

Comment: I get an error from Swift saying, Cannot convert value of type 'AdColonyInterstitial' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Comment: I'm not familiar with the AdColony library, but you need to have a ViewController to be able to show it.

Comment: Can you try `interstitial.show(withPresenting: vc)` instead of `present`

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me. Referred to image_picker plugin.

```
public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    switch call.method {
    case "startTestActivity":
        let vc = YourViewController()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen;
        viewController(with: nil)?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        result(true)
    default:
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    }
}

func viewController(with window: UIWindow?) -> UIViewController? {
    var windowToUse = window
    if windowToUse == nil {
        for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
            if window.isKeyWindow {
                windowToUse = window
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    var topController = windowToUse?.rootViewController
    while ((topController?.presentedViewController) != nil) {
        topController = topController?.presentedViewController
    }
    return topController
}
```