# Flutter - How to invoke channel in native Swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I have written native Swift code in my `AppDelegate`, I am trying to invoke a third party sdk callback in my dart side of code, however the declaration of my method channel can only be done in `application` function. How do I invoke a channel in my delegate methods to make a dart callback?

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, TJPlacementDelegate {
    
    public func requestDidSucceed(_ placement: TJPlacement!) {
       //Need to invoke methodChannel here
    }
    public func requestDidFail(_ placement: TJPlacement!, error: Error!) {
      //Need to invoke methodChannel here
    }
    public func contentIsReady(_ placement: TJPlacement!) {
      //Need to invoke methodChannel here
    }
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        
        let channelName = "ios_native"
        let rootViewController : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: channelName, binaryMessenger: rootViewController as! FlutterBinaryMessenger)
        
        methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler {(call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
            switch(call.method) {
            case "setDebugEnabled":
                let isDebug = call.arguments as! Bool
                Tapjoy.setDebugEnabled(isDebug)
                break;
            default: result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            }
        }
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        
    }
     
}
```

I can't declare my `methodChannel` outside my application as the `window` doesn't get recognised.

Comment: Why do you need methodChannel? If you want to use it to return a result you can define the result in the class, and initialize it in `application()`

Comment: Could show me a programatic example? @SamiHaddad

Comment: Check if the answer below helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the method channel in the AppDelegate:

```
var methodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel!
```

Initialize it:

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
  ...
    
  methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: channelName, binaryMessenger: rootViewController as! FlutterBinaryMessenger)

}
```

Now you can call invokeMethod:

```
public func requestDidSucceed(_ placement: TJPlacement!) {
  methodChannel.invokeMethod()
}
```

Comment: I want to invoke a method for my dart side of code to work, so is there a way I can invoke a channel instead of FlutterResult?

Comment: So you want to call a dart function?

Comment: Yes, I have a listener that will get triggered when a reward callback has to be fired. So I want the reward value to be called in my dart side of code from my swift side of code, basically I want to call channel.invokeMethod('abc');

Comment: Define rootViewController the same way I defined result.

Comment: My app crashes, as it says the value hasn't been initialised.

Comment: Could you please update your code to show a proper implementation? @SamiHaddad

Comment: Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, it worked wonderfully! @SamHaddad.  Could you also give this question a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62175368/which-view-controller-should-i-pass-in-my-swift-native-code-for-a-flutter-plugin